# Need to convert char* to string or other type in order to run hash on it

Tags: c++, type-conversion, mp3

I need to read in an mp3 file so that I can run the hash(). I do not need to parse the mp3 tag data out of this so I can just read the whole thing all together.

Currently I am using ifstream() to open the file in binary mode. I then get the size of the file, allocate enough space with a char* and read it all at once.

I know that when I run cout on this data I can only see "ID3 and some gibberish." I opened the mp3 file up in a hex editor and ID3 and the gibberish was what was at the beginning of the file. The next binary data I believe is being interpreted as end of line/string and does not print.

This is okay because I don't need to print it. I need to get the data in a format that I can run the Hash function on. Any ideas on a type I can convert it to that will not interpret the end of the file being a couple bytes in?

Here is code of what I have so far.

```
bool Sender::openSoundFile(){
    streampos size;
    soundSampleStream.open(soundFilePath.c_str(), ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
    if(!soundSampleStream.is_open()){
        return false;
    }
    size = soundSampleStream.tellg();
    cout << "Size of MP3: " << size << endl;
    soundFileInMemory = new char [size];

    soundSampleStream.seekg (0, ios::beg);
    soundSampleStream.read(soundFileInMemory, size);
    cout << "Error is: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
    cout << "gcount: " << soundSampleStream.gcount() << endl;
    soundSampleStream.close();

    cout << soundFileInMemory << endl;

    return true;
}
```

I get no error on reading the file and gcount() comes back with the correct numbers of bytes for the file.

Edit 1:
To add some more on this. The hash() seems to hash the char* and not the data being pointed at because the hash value changes on different program runs. This is why I need to convert to some other thing. I also don't think that a vector is supported by the c++11 hash().

Comment: AFAICS the only problem in this code is a memory leak. Well, and possible UB for the output statement. You can avoid the leak by using a `std::vector<unsigned char>` as buffer.

Comment: soundFileInMemory is part of the parent object and gets deleted by the deconstructor if that was what you were referring to.

Answer (score 0):

std::string has a constructor that takes a char * and a size_t. See the fourth item in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string.

```
std::string file_contents(soundFileInMemory, size);
```

That will convert your char array to a string.

Comment: Some Google library uses `std::string` for arbitrary binary data. That's technically OK and convenient for the cases where the data is text, but it's misleading and problematic for the general case. I can't see any good reason to repeat that unfortunate choice.

Comment: Interesting point. What data structure would you suggest? std::string has the advantage of a simple constructor and a pre-defined hash function which are the two things the OP asked for. If you hid the name behind a typedef, would you consider that reasonable style? Or is the problem that std::string might have implementation details that do not suit binary data?

Comment: `std::vector<Byte>` (where `Byte` is `unsigned char`) is a good choice. One can use Boost `hash` directly, or one can define a hash function for vectors using e.g. `h1 ^ (h2 << 1)` to combine two sequential hashes `h1` and `h2` so that the result depends on the order. I didn't know that the standard library is so limited compared to Boost, it's inexplicable.